# Prove a predicate formula in the constructive logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, formal-proofs

Using the constructive logic (the axiom $A\lor\lnot A$ cannot be used), using quantifier axioms and Modus Ponens, and Generalization, prove the following:

$\exists x(B(x) \to C(x)) \to (\forall xB(x) \to \exists x C(x))$

Taking as hypotheses:

$\exists x(B(x) \to C(x))$ ;

$\forall xB(x)$ ;

We now need to show that

$ \exists x C(x) $

and then by Deduction theorem 2 we will be able to say that there is a proof of the initial formula.

I can get only so far that I get $B(x)$ and then I'm stuck.
How should I approach this?

Note that $B \to C$ cannot be substituted by $\lnot B\lor C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from $\exists x(B(x) \to C(x))$ and use existential instantiation with the new introduced constant (variable) $a$ to get $B(a) \to C(a).$ Now apply $\forall x B(x)$ by universal instantiation to get $B(a).$ At this point from modus ponens and the two already shown $B(a)$ and $B(a) \to C(a),$ we get to $C(a),$ and then using existential generalization finally arrive at $\exists x C(x).$

Note: I assume your system must have versions of universal/existential instantiation and existential generalization. Without something like that I don't see how to prove it either.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it had to do with existential instantiation, I just couldn't figure it out till the end.

Comment: When I did logic we used Kalish and Montague, and that system was enjoyable to use. It had plenty of examples where the instantiation and generalization rules were applied, as well as strict rules of how to formally do it in proofs which would guarantee one would not prove anything that is false. The tricky part was deciding what to do next. Only experience can teach that skill, but it's fun trying...